# jquery plugin development : prototype callback arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, callback

I've never really developed jquery plugins and I'm missing something with the concept... 
I'm trying to modify this [image cropping plugin](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) to have a new callback to set the aspect ratio dynamically.

So in cropper.js, I added a callback like this :

```
Cropper.prototype = {
    construstor: Cropper,

    //init function with init code

    //My new function
    setAspectRatio: function(ratio) {
        console.log(ratio);
        this.disable();
        this.defaults.aspectRatio = ratio;
        this.enable();
    },

    //more functions here ...

}
```

And in my view :

```
var $cropper = $(".cropper");
//call the cropper
$cropper.cropper({ aspectRatio: 580 / 280 });
//change the ratio
$cropper.cropper("setAspectRatio",1600/585);
```

But the ratio is not passed to the callback. The console.log() outputs undefined.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please show us the definition of the `$.fn.cropper` function, which is the one you're calling on `$cropper` and that should forward the "method call".

Comment: Here is the full source (it will get messy if I copy too much code into the question) : https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/master/src/cropper.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to pass arguments to the instance methods from the jQuery collection method, you will need to change the lines

```
        …
        if (typeof options === "string" && $.isFunction(data[options])) {
            data[options]();
        }
        …
```

in `$.fn.cropper` (at the very end of the file) to

```
// Register as jQuery plugin
$.fn.cropper = function(options) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data("cropper");

        if (!data) {
            data = new Cropper(this, options);
            $this.data("cropper", data);
        }

        if (typeof options === "string" && $.isFunction(data[options])) {
            data[options].apply(data, args);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's somewhat working, but the $cropper.cropper("setAspectRatio",1600/585); is passing the HTMLImage element to the function instead of the ratio I'm giving, would you be so kind to clarify...?

Comment: Oops, right, that passes the arguments of the `each` callback. Adapted :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, you really helped me! I'm starting to grasp the way it's working now